# Can not put in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to put every char (as int) and its count in a Hashmap.
However, when I print out the map, the values are always null.
Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

```java
public class CharCounter implements IHuffConstants, ICharCounter {

    private static Map<Integer, Integer> table;

    CharCounter(){
        table = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }


    /**
     * Initialize state by counting bits/chunks in a stream
     * @param stream is source of data
     * @return count of all chunks/read
     * @throws IOException if reading fails
     */
    @Override
    public int countAll(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];

        while ((nRead = stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
          buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        byte[] result = buffer.toByteArray();

        for(int i =0 ; i<result.length;i++) {           
            table.put((int)result[i],table.getOrDefault(result[i],0)+1);
            System.out.println(result[i] +","+table.get(result[i]));
        }
        return result.length;
    }
```

output:
(test the word "testing")

```
116,null
101,null
115,null
116,null
115,null
116,null
114,null
105,null
110,null
103,null
```

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement here other than "what's wrong with my code?"  Please elaborate on what the problem is, tell us what the code is trying to do, and mention what you have tried so far to fix the problem.

Comment: I notice you don't cast to an `int` when you retrieve the previous results.  In Java, boxing to a byte and to an int are likely to produce different results.  Try: `table.getOrDefault((int)result[i],0)`

Comment: Also, same comment for retrieval and printing: `System.out.println(result[i] +","+table.get(result[i]));` ... might need to be ... `System.out.println(result[i] +","+table.get((int)result[i]));`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The question is perfectly clear.  Elaine has explained what she's trying to achieve, shown us some code, and shown us what the (incorrect) output was.  She wants to know what's wrong with the code, that has made the output different from what she wanted.  I don't see how she could have made it clearer.

Comment: Also the combination of making the table static and initializing it in the constructor is really bad.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that the code you're showing us is NOT the actual code that's executing @Elaine ... check your save and execution paths